# Force Close a file not a process

Tags: windows, scripting, files

I want to write a script that forces closed a specific file and then copies it from one server to another.

To manually do this I would use

Administrative Tools --> Computer Management --> Shared Folders --> Open Files

Is there a way to script this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used the SysInternals utility [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) in the past and wrapped a script around that before.

You could also use the command:

```
net file /close
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but be careful OP, as force-closing a handle out from underneath the process that was using it can cause that process to crash or behave unpredictably.

Comment: +1 I agree that it can cause instability in the server/application depending on the application and the file you are closing. Generally, applications hold files open for a reason - but, I've had instances where a poorly-written app was misbehaving.. caution is always advised though and I generally wouldn't rely on this for production level solutions.